# PHP are sessions safe

Tags: php

```
if($_POST['user'] == 'anita' && $_POST['pw'] == '123')
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
    echo "Welcome, " . $user;
    $loggedin = true;
}else
{
    die('Log in details incorrect.');
}

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   // Show website edit menu
}
```

I'm creating a website and I was thinking about adding a small self made CMS for my customer to use, so she can update the site herself.

Is this a safe way to save someones details? can I just check if $_SESSION['username'] is set to validate that the user is logged in?

Comment: Sessions are fine, but I would hope that you would check far more than just whether or not you set a username in your session.  I verify password every time.  This also allows logging someone out upon password change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, thats all I needed to know. Dont know why anyone votes me down. I just wanted to make sure this is safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes.
Setting a session on a server side it pretty safe, as it means the hacker will have to get access to server files writing, or find a really horrible bug in your client code that leads to file rewrites.

Just do some research for: session fixation and how to prevent it, and try to use SSL on the CMS side.

Answer (score 2):

Session files are generally saved purely on the server, and the only thing the user has direct access to is the session cookie. That cookie will also usually only have the ID of the session in it and nothing else.

Unless a malicious user has other means of access the session storage system (files, database) by some means OTHER than your code, then there's no way they can change anything stored in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, sessions are safe. However there are susceptible to hi-jacking. 
Sessions are uniquely identified by a session ID, which is stored on the server; this is your sole link between your server and computer. 
If someone were to obtain this ID, then they have access to your session.

Darius

Comment: And thats where SSL comes into play? How does one obtain the ID?